# Checkbox click event not triggered in android listview with checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I am trying to implement an android listview with checkbox. However, I am unable to get the click event for my checkbox.

I can make the code work if I put the checkbox listener on the adapter class. However I need the information at the main class instead.

Using the main class, I can get the event for listview when clicked but not the checkbox using lv.onItemClick. However, I need to click on the listview once and the checkbox again in order for the checkbox event to be triggered. I need the checkbox event and the listview click event seperately. Any help? Thanks

XML FOR LIST
There is still a linear layout outside the Relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title_paper"

        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cbPaper"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />


     <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary_paper"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cbPaper"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title_paper"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title_paper"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"


        />  



     <CheckBox
         android:button="@null"
         android:id="@+id/cbPaper"
         android:layout_width="35dp"
         android:layout_height="35dp"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@drawable/customcbpaper"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
         android:gravity="right" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

EVENT HANDLER ON MAIN

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                   checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbPaper);
                   checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View v) 
                     {
                         Log.w("do something", "do something" );
                     } });

            }
    });

}
```

public class CustAdapHeaderWithCbPaper extends ArrayAdapter   {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;


public CustAdapHeaderWithCbPaper(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView a;
    protected TextView b;
       protected CheckBox cb;
      }



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final int newPosition = position;

    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        if(i.isSection()){
            SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);

            final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
            sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
        }
        else //Not a section
        {

            EntryItemCheckBox ei = (EntryItemCheckBox)i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry_cb_paper, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.a =  (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title_paper);
            holder.b =  (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary_paper);
            holder.cb =  (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.cbPaper);
            final String titleCheck = ei.title.toString();

             holder.cb.setTag(position); 
             holder.a.setText(ei.title);
             holder.cb.setChecked(ei.selected);



             v.setTag(holder);
             v.setTag(R.id.list_item_entry_title_paper, holder.a);
             v.setTag(R.id.list_item_entry_summary_paper, holder.b);
             v.setTag(R.id.cbPaper, holder.cb);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: You should put the `checkbox listener` in adapter class only. Then notify the `main activit`y through a custom `interface listeners`.

Comment: check this out 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699062/assinging-the-values-of-cursor-to-object/20739752?noredirect=1#comment31076084_20739752'. It has the Array adapter in answer section.

Comment: How can i write the custom interface listeners? i need the results of checkbox in the main class

Answer (score 2):

You are mentioning `android:clickable="false"` for the `checkBox` in the xml...So the checkBox cannot listen the click event..and better put the listener in the Adapter class..

You `setOnCheckedChangeListener` rather than `setOnClickListener`

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am mentioning android:focusable="false", so that checkbox only get focus explicitly, and by default list view row should get focus.

Comment: Hi, it will get the same error even if I use the on click listener

Comment: I need the results of listener is main class. what should i do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

in your listview xml. It will be helpful I think. Let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

outside the first `if(i!=null)` condition find the checkbox and do the same work you need

for instance:

```
holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) 
                 {
                     Log.w("do something", "do something" );
                 } });
```

To get the entire `RelativeLayout` click event give a **id** in **xml** and do the same

Comment: I need the setClickListener in the main class rather than in the adapter class. Any help? Thanks

Comment: @user313408 it's better to write the click listener inside the `getView()` why do you need that in **main**. You want the checkbox object to live outside the local scope????

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove this line from your Xml file

```
android:button=null
```

and add this line to Your checkbox

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Then, use this code it will work for you

```
   checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  if(checkBox.isChecked())
                                     {
                            // do what You want to perform on when check box is checked
                                             }
                                 else
                                {
                                             }
                            }
                         });
```

and provide separate event for list view like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {


            }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, However if i use the onClick(View v) there will be an error

Comment: This is because i need the view and i need position of the listview as well. Any help? Thanks